# how do i set environment variables in invokeprocess in TFS 2010

Tags: workflow

I am trying to set new environment variables in InvokeProcess in tfs2010, I tried creating a variable ENV_VAR of type IDictionary() and then in InvokeProcess then I tried adding new variable as ENV_VAR.Add("New","Variable") but it shows me an error.
Thanks
/G

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For someone with similar issue , I managed to resolve it  , Way to define EnvironmentVariable in InvokeProcess activity
New Dictionary(Of String, String) From {{"Key1", "Value1"}, {"key2", "value2"}}